# Variadic arguments don't work in AIX 5.3 on CC compiler

Tags: c, macros

I currently have a bunch of debug macros (hijacked from Zed's book Learn C The Hard Way) and I'm trying to compile them on AIX. The macros:

```
#ifndef __dbg_h__
#define __dbg_h__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define debug(M, s ...)
#else
#define debug(M, s ...) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ## s)
#endif

#define clean_errno() (errno == 0 ? "None" : strerror(errno))


#define log_err(M, s ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ## s)

#define log_warn(M, s ...) fprintf(stderr, "[WARN] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ## s)

#define log_info(M, s ...) fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] (%s:%d) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ## s)

#define check(A, M, s ...) if(!(A)) { log_err(M, ## s); errno=0; goto error; }

#define sentinel(M, s ...)  { log_err(M, ## s); errno=0; goto error; }

#define check_mem(A) check((A), "Out of memory.")

#define check_debug(A, M, s ...) if(!(A)) { debug(M, ## s); errno=0; goto error; }

#endif
```

When I compile my project that imports these macros, the AIX CC compiler prints compiler errors with this message, and then exits normally:

```
"src/dbg.h", line 13.19: 1506-211 (S) Parameter list must be empty, or consist of one or more identifiers separated by commas.
```

It prints one of these to every line in the project that use one of the macro functions.

I've tried setting `#pragma langlvl (stdc99)` and `#pragma langlvl (extc99)` as advised in this [article](http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/26/portable-__va_args__-macros-for-linux-hp-ux-solaris-and-aix/) with no success.

I've also written a small example to see if I can compile it, as follows:

```
/* file "test.c" */
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTERROR(M, s...) fprintf(stderr, "ERROR MSG: " M "\n", ## s)

int main(void) {
  PRINTERROR("no args");
  PRINTERROR("with args: %s", "foo");
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler emits the following message:

```
"test.c", line 4.24: 1506-211 (S) Parameter list must be empty, or consist of one or more identifiers separated by commas.
```

I'm using `AIX 5.3` and `CC for AIX version 6.0.0.0`.

Comment: It dies? File bug report then. It should report the errors and terminate normally (just with an error-code).

Comment: This compiles and works fine for me with a `int main() { debug( "%d", 42 ); }` added. AIX 6.1, XL C/C++ v11.1. Please post a *complete* example, and the version of compiler you're using.

Comment: @Olaf: Note that he *did* post the error message generated by the compiler. His use of "it died" is unfortunate but does not indicate an actual compiler fault.

Comment: @Olaf edited answer. The compiler emits a message and then exits normally. I don't think it's his fault, but mine.

Comment: You have edited your question so that instead of the standard syntax for variadic macros ( `...`/`__VA_ARGS__`) the proprietary syntax ( `s...`/`s`)  is used. Can you reproduce the error in your example with the standard syntax?

Comment: @thepanuto: Ugh... version 6? That's *ancient*. Your edited example compiles & executes fine for me as well. Together with the answers already posted, I'd suspect the GNU extension syntax for the macro was introduced into XL C/C++ somewhere between your v6 and my v11.

Comment: @DevSolar well, it's a program for another company, they assured me that the xlC toolchain was updated. Guess they lied. I had assumed that my code was causing the issue, but maybe updating the compiler would make these problems go away? Since my program compiles on GCC v4.9.2

Comment: @MOehm I can reproduce with both syntaxes. Pretty weird, huh?

Comment: @thepanuto: I cannot find a version history for XL C/C++ right now, but version v6 could possibly even predate the introduction of variadic macros...

Comment: @DevSolar I see. Well, that would be the case, then. I saw a thread which they had this problem and it was a bug in the xlC compiler. Maybe the machine owners should update the compiler and we'll call it closed.

Comment: @thepanuto: "IBM VisualAge C++ Professional for AIX, V6.0" was announced July 2002... "updated" my behind. :-D

Comment: @DevSolar so much for a latest version, huh? 2002 isn't that long ago, right? What could we possibly be missing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code -- either the original version or the edited one, which is using a non-standard extension, see the answer by ouah -- compiles fine for me on AIX 6.1 using XL C/C++ v11.1.

You state that your compiler is `CC for AIX version 6.0.0.0`. If that is to mean "IBM VisualAge C++ Professional for AIX, V6.0", that version was [announced in 2002](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&htmlfid=897/ENUS202-162), i.e. is not really up to date...

Variadic macros in turn were included in the standard only in 1999, so it's quite possible your version of the compiler does not support them yet.

Answer (score 2):

The form:

```
#define debug(M, s ...) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ## s)
```

with `s ...` is not C but a GNU extension to C. See gcc [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) that states:

> If your macro is complicated, you may want a more descriptive name for the variable argument than **VA_ARGS**. CPP permits this, as an extension. You may write an argument name immediately before the ‘...’; that name is used for the variable argument. The eprintf macro above could be written

```
 #define eprintf(args...) fprintf (stderr, args)
```

> using this extension.

The correct C form for your `debug` macro would be:

```
#define debug(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n", __FILE__,
         __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```